# When to use "be going to" / present continuous in future?

Tags: grammar, future-tense, present-continuous

In our lesson we have

#### Be going to

- future plans (personal)
- prediction based on something we can see or hear

#### Present continuous

- future arrangement
- fixed plan

Is this right? Can someone explain this to me with examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use "be going to" for your future plans - the things you intend/have decided to do in the future.  For example:

I am going to have a meal with my friends tonight.

you can also use "be going to" for a prediction as you see or hear.  For example:

There are clouds in the sky. It's going to rain.

You use the present continuous for future arrangements and fixed plans. For example:

I am going to an ice hockey match in the evening. I bought a ticket for it yesterday.

Nevertheless, you often use either be going to or the present continuous to have similar  meanings.

We are going to have a party next week (we intend/have decided to do so).

We are having a party next week (we have made arrangements).

Comment: (1) The question is about “be going to” vs. present continuous, and your example of present continuous uses the verb **to go**. This is confusing. I suggest that you change your ice hockey example to something like “I am watching a movie …”, “I am attending a lecture …”, or “I am visiting a friend …”.  (2) IMHO, your answer would be easier to read if you visually distinguished the sentences that are *talking about* the language from the examples. Blockquotes (`> ` *`blah blah blah …`*) work well (see [LawrenceC’s answer](/q/56094/357#56096)); bullets (`- ` *`blah blah blah …`*) work well, too.

Answer (score 2):

> I am walking in the park.

This means you are walking in the park right now as you say this.

> I am going to walk in the park

This can mean the same as *I will walk in the park.*

Both of these can mean *to intend soon* - as in *I intend soon to walk in the park*.